# How to use std::string in a QLineEdit?

Tags: c++, qt, stdstring, qstring

I have the following problem. I am trying to integrate a large code written by me with a Qt interface.

Some of my functions return `std::string`. I did not succeed in making `QLineEdit::setText` accept them (other functions returning `char` do not give me problems).

What should I do? Thanks!
Giuseppe

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

```
std::string a = "aaa";
lineEdit->setText(QString::fromStdString(a));
```

You will need Qt with STL support.

Answer (score 1):

There's no constructor for `QString` that takes a `std::string`. Convert it first to a C string using `std::string::c_str()`.

Comment: Ugly, I was hoping to find something better. I have learnt in Meyer's books to use string instead of char whenever possible: how is it possible for QT not handle strings properly?

Comment: @Giuseppe: Qt has its own QTL and its own string class. Most Qt containers and QString can be converted from/to their STL counterparts if your version of Qt was compiled in STL compatibility mode. AFAIK this mode is the default.

Comment: They expect you to use `QString`. I'd have a look at rpg's answer, looks way better than mine. Another possibility is of course to hack Qt's code, that should be a matter of 10 minutes.